How do I create a custom mathematical expression formula that describes an ethereum private key to address using eth_account?
I'm coding in python and I'm trying to create my own custom mathematical formula expression that will describe how a private key turns into an address. I know that this isn't commonly done but I'm trying to use this so I can set up my own cryptocurrency app that let's me perform tasks that I will use for this.
By mathematical expression I mean something that is like y = (ax + b) but it will turn a private key into an address using the formula.
The code I'm using so far is posted below.
@combomethod
def from_key2(self, private_key: PrivateKeyType) -> LocalAccount:
    #Put formula in integer3 to calculate address then put formula outside parenthesis


    integer2 = LocalAccount(keys.PrivateKey(private_key.to_bytes(32, 'big')), self).address
    integer3 = 'formula here from variable integer2'
   
    return integer3

This is a copy of the from_key from Account.from_key() in eth_account. It turns a private key integer into an address. I want to use that formula to create my own mathematical expression in integer3 that will let me do the same thing but except I can use a mathematical expression to do it for my cryptocurrency platform.

Well, you would start at looking at what the LocalAccount.address property does. Then you'll probably need to look at how the keys.PrivateKey constructor works, etc. Then, eventually, you'll have figured out all the pieces and you'll have replaced the integer2 = ... statement with your own code.

You'll need to be way more specific. (42) is also a formula, even simpler than ax+b. I suspect you want some sort of hash, though, but this needs to be exactly specified for a cryptocurrency. If you include the specification in the question, we can help with the Python. Note that a bad specification probably breaks your crypto security.

@AKX Please can you show me how to do this. I'm using the libraries eth_keys for the integer part and eth_account for the address part. Where would I convert to a mathematical equation?

@MSalters What do you mean by speification??

@user27394478 If you're using an IDE like VS Code or PyCharm, you should be able to ctrl-click/cmd-click "through" to e.g. .address to see the source code.

@AKX I already know this I'm using pycharm. I want to know what to do once I get inside the source code for the .address part please help me sir please

You read it to learn it how it works – having a piece of paper to jot down things might help – and then you reimplement it. I can't really teach or help you to read and learn.

@user27394478: If you're unfamiliar with the idea of a "specification", then you do not have the necessary skills yet to develop something as complex as a cryptocurrency. A specification in short says what a certain program should do, without saying how it should do that.
